# Does Apple allow free apps with disabled features that, when clicked on, display a prompt to purchase content?

Tags: ios, iphone

I have been reading The Business of iPhone and iPad App Development: Making and Marketing Apps that Succeed (http://www.amazon.com/Business-iPhone-iPad-Development-ebook/dp/B004TMNSJK/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1340317546&sr=8-2&keywords=marketing+iphone+apps). The book is a little old (about a year at this point, which is a long time considering how long the app store has been around).

The book claims the Apple's iPhone development guidelines/rules state that an app must be fully functional. The book says that because of this rule, a "free" or "lite" version of an app cannot display buttons that appear to be functional but, when clicked on, prompt the user to purchase the full version of the app. For example, imagine a GPS app that has a button labeled "Give me turn-by-turn directions as I drive". If you click on the button, it just pops up a dialogue that says "Buy the full version to unlock this feature". According to this book, that app would be rejected by the Apple review team.

I have an app that allows users to download extra content with an in-app purchase. I would like to display the content as "grayed out". If the user clicks on the locked content, I want to display a popup that tells them how they can get the additional content. According to the book, this behavior will be rejected.

However, since this design is so important to my app, I've spent some time reading through all of the iPhone app guidelines, including the In-App Purchases guidelines, and I have found NOTHING that leads me to the conclusion that this sort of behavior is not allowed.

Since the app review process is currently sitting at about a week, I don't want to lose a full week of app purchases because of a rejection for this. Has anyone ever heard of this rule, and if so, can you please point me to it?

Thank you.

Comment: Why can't you just have a Lite version and a Full version? Is that an issue? Or can you have an in-app store for features that you manage with Store Kit?

Comment: Because I'm allowing them to download additional content rather than additional functionality. I think the in-app purchase model fits that better.

Comment: Don't you mean that the other way around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a "Free" or "Lite" app recently submitted (and accepted) to the App Store, where some `UITextField`s were greyed out and when touched, a `UIAlertView` was displayed . I don't know if this would be acceptable with buttons but it seems like more or less the same thing.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you! Unfortunately, I have found Apple's review team to be very inconsistent. Hopefully they give me the same treatment.

Comment: Just to add, I remember a few months back when reading the iOS Submission Guidelines in Apple's documentation, there was a paragraph very similar to the one you described from your book. So my suggestion would be to make it as subtle as possible and not too aggressive in terms of trying to get the user to purchase more content.

Answer (score 1):

I think the book is probably right. Please check this [link](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/submission/tips.html) or read below.

> *The two most common reasons for application rejection are issues with core functionality and crashing. Core functionality encompasses the belief that customers rightfully expect all the features described in the marketing text and release notes to work as described, and likewise that all the buttons and menu items within the application will be fully functional (i.e., **no grayed out buttons or notifications that a feature will be implemented later**). Before you submit your app for approval, make sure that every aspect of your application is fully functional and that the marketing text and release notes correspond to the end user experience.*

Comment: The link you're quoting from is dead, and searches for snippets of that text only lead back here. https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/rejections/ might be the new place to look, but it doesn't mention the above. Nor can I find conclusive evidence in the official guidelines. So maybe the rules changed once again?